# View getVisibility() isShown() return incorrect visibility

Tags: android

I've a view that gets conditionally added to parent.
I check if its already added to parent or not, unfortunately, it always return its visible.

```
if (findViewById(R.id.bottom_bar).getVisibility == View.Visible)

if (findViewById(R.id.bottom_bar).isShown())
```

both return `true` even when view was never added ans is not visible.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

`getVisibility()` simply returns the visibility you want the view to have when added to the window. It doesn't change unless you call `setVisibility()`. It also doesn't indicate whether the view is actually visible on screen.

`isShown()` is similar. Here is the doc:

> Returns the visibility of this view and all of its ancestors
>
> **Returns**
>   True if this view and all of its ancestors are `VISIBLE`

Comment: Also if the app is in the background (e.g. homescreen is active), then `isShown()` is false, regardless of what `getVisibility()` returns.

Comment: @gattsbr I was looking at the source code and was not able to understand how the app backgrounded case is handled. It does return false though like you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

I've had to do something similar and I tend to ask the view if it has a parent (myView.getParent() != null) then I assume the view has been added to another view. Often to hide the view I remove it from the parent. You could also override the onDraw method and if you don't get calls to draw, you certainly aren't visible.

Answer (score -2):

If `findViewById(R.id.bottom_bar)` returned non-null, then at least one bottom_bar View is already instantiated somewhere in the View hierarchy. That's your check.