# How to test if a fragment view is visible to the user?

Tags: android, user-interface, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a ViewPager, each page is a Fragment view. I want to test if a fragment is in a visible region. the Fragment.isVisible only test

- the fragment is attached to a activity
- the fragment is set to visible
- the fragment has been added to a view

The ViewPager will create 3 (by default) fragment and all three of them meet the above criteria, but only one is actually visible to the user (the human **eyes**)

Comment: please post your code for better help.

Comment: I sure would love to know that too at the moment.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**You're right there is a better way to do this!**

Have a look at the [FragmentPagerAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html) javadoc online and you'll see there is a method [setPrimaryItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object):void](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html#setPrimaryItem%28android.view.ViewGroup,%20int,%20java.lang.Object%29) doing exactly what you need.

**From the javadoc**

> public void setPrimaryItem (ViewGroup container, int position, Object object)
>
> Called to inform the adapter of which item is currently considered to
>   be the "primary", that is the one show to the user as the current
>   page.
>
> Parameters container  The containing View from which the page will be
>   removed. position The page position that is now the primary.
>   object    The same object that was returned by instantiateItem(View,
>   int).

**Note on scroll state**

Now if you implement this and start debugging to get a feel of when exactly this is called you'll quickly notice this is triggered several times on preparing the fragment and while the user is swiping along.

So it might be a good idea to also attach a [ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.html#onPageScrollStateChanged%28int%29) and only do what has to be done once the viewpagers scroll state becomes [SCOLL_STATE_IDLE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) again.

Comment: this approach works great if one extends the `Application` class and has to test whether a particular UI is showing. I just ended up using several booleans to test whether the app was backgrounded, and whether a particular fragment was showing.

Answer (score 66):

This is what I use to determine the visibility of a fragment.

```
private static boolean m_iAmVisible;

@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) { 
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    m_iAmVisible = isVisibleToUser;

    if (m_iAmVisible) { 
        Log.d(localTAG, "this fragment is now visible");
    } else {  
        Log.d(localTAG, "this fragment is now invisible");
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not work as per documentation: "Set a hint to the system about whether this fragment's UI is currently visible to the user. This hint defaults to true and is persistent across fragment instance state save and restore"

Comment: Good solution (+1) but code can be simplified:

         `public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {

        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);

        m_iAmVisible = false;  //default to not visible

        if (isVisibleToUser) { 

            m_iAmVisible = true;

        }
    }`

Comment: simplified is: public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) { super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser); m_iAmVisible = isVisibleToUser;}

Comment: even simpler, `getUserVisibleHint()`

Comment: THIS HELPS A LOT THANK YOU!

Answer (score 9):

For my purposes, it worked to use `ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.onPageSelected()` in conjunction with `Fragment.onActivityCreated()` to perform an action when the Fragment is visible. `Fragment.getUserVisibleHint()` helps too.

Answer (score 3):

I'm using "setMenuVisibility"-Method for resolving this Problem. As every Fragment can have actionbar-items this is the part where you can determine which Fragment is currently visible to the user.

```
@Override
public void setMenuVisibility(final boolean visible) {
    super.setMenuVisibility(visible);
    if (!visible) {
        //not visible anymore
    }else{
        yay visible to the user
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

What is wrong with using `getView().isShown()` to find out if a Fragment is actually visible?

Comment: Have you tested your idea? I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6796299/view-getvisibility-isshown-return-incorrect-visibility) post pointed out the same idea.

Comment: Yes. It works for me, as suggested in the linked post.

Answer (score 3):

```
isVisible()
```

Can still return true even if the fragment is behind an activity.

I'm using the following:

```
if (getView() != null && getView().isShown()) {
//your code here
}
```

Comment: according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6796299/view-getvisibility-isshown-return-incorrect-visibility) , `isShown` is similar to `getVisibility()` so it can still return true if `VISIBLE` but behind an activity

Answer (score 2):

If you know what "page" each fragment is attached to you could use ViewPager.getCurrentItem() to determine which fragment is "visible".

Comment: This is what I am doing right now. I am just thinking if there's other ways. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In my case i a have to do some  work on the first fragment when the fragment is visible to the user

```
 @Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);


    if(viewPager.getAdapter() instanceof YourPager)
    {
        Fragment fragemnt=((YourPager)viewPager.getAdapter()).getFragment(0); //getFragment(int index) custom method
        if( fragemnt instanceof YourFragment)
        {
            ((YourFragment)fragemnt).methodWhochShouldBeCalledAfterUIVisible();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`setUserVisibleHint` probably may not be called, `onHiddenChanged` may be called not every time when another fragment is being closed. So, you may rely on `onResume` (and `onPause`), but it is usually called too often (for example, when you turn on a device screen). Also in some situations it is not called, you should manage current fragment in host activity and write:

```
if (currentFragment != null) {
    currentFragment.onResume();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin:

```
if (userVisibleHint) {
    // the fragment is visible
} else {
    // the fragment is not visible
}
```

Java

```
if (getUserVisibleHint()) {
    // the fragment is visible
} else {
    // the fragment is not visible
}
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getUserVisibleHint()

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12523627/2069407

Comment: Depreciated in API 27