# Hide menu options in action bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have one activity with 3 fragments (not tabs). I have several action bar items and I would like to hide them when a certain fragment is present. How can i go about this?

Comment: Showing/hiding the action bar items; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10692755/how-do-i-hide-a-menu-item-in-the-actionbar Usefull blog post: http://android-er.blogspot.nl/2013/05/show-and-hide-menu-item-programatically.html Checking if fragment is visible to user: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9323279/how-to-test-if-a-fragment-view-is-visible-to-the-user

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
@Override
public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);

    MenuItem item3  = menu.findItem(R.id.ID OF MENU);
    item3.setVisible(false);
}
```

Comment: Two questions: 1.) Are you referring to the method in the activity or the fragment? 2.) This works well with a few items but if I have many items i will have to set them false and then make them visible again when i need them..

Comment: @AndroidEnthusiast i'm referring it in fragment then make group of menu items and toggle visibility of group.

Answer (score 3):

If you wish to hide ALL menu items, just do:

```
@Override
public void onAttach(final Activity activity) {

    super.onAttach(activity);

    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}

@Override
public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(final Menu menu) {

    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);

    menu.clear();//This removes all menu items (no need to know the id of each of them)
}
```

Comment: +1 for that! Actually, just putting `return false;` as the only statement within `onPrepareOptionsMenu()` also removes the whole menu.

Comment: @1111161171159459134 how do you return false in a 'void' function?

Comment: @zdd I don't know how; the fact is that `return false;` does remove the whole menu! Did you try it?

Comment: @1111161171159459134, we have some gap, this function return boolean in Activity but return void in Fragment, that's the difference.

Answer (score 1):

**What i understand with your post is**::

1. You have 3 fragments
2. You have 3 different set of actionbar buttons for 3 fragments

---

***My preferred approach***::**`You can also find the menu items which you dont want to display in your current fragment and set their visibility`**

```
MenuItem item = menu.findItem(<id>);
item.setVisible(<true/false>);
```

**ex**::

```
MenuItem item1 = menu.findItem(R.id.searchID);
item1.setVisible(false);
```

---

### You can also use [this post](https://www.grokkingandroid.com/adding-action-items-from-within-fragments/) for a different approach to handle this problem

---