# How to tell if a fragment is on the screen, visible in a ViewPager?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, handler

I am trying to get a handler to start as soon as the fragment appears on screen to the user. 
I have tried many other ways and they all seem to start the handler thread before the fragment appears to the user. Usually the fragment before triggers it.

The isVisible() method that is floating around other threads says a fragment is visible when it isn't on the screen.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to test if a fragment view is visible to the user?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9323279/how-to-test-if-a-fragment-view-is-visible-to-the-user)

Answer (score 1):

One way to handle it is with the [getUserVisibleHint()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#getUserVisibleHint()) or [setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#setUserVisibleHint(boolean)) Method of the Fragment. The other way would be to add a [ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.html) and in the [onPageSelected](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.html#onPageSelected(int)) method you know the position of the selected fragment and react to it.