# Having a custom View determine its own visibility

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I want to create a custom `View` that has display logic to determine its own visibility.  In the interest of keeping that logic contained and easily reusable, I created a `View` subclass, overrode `getVisibility()` and was planning on invalidating the `View` when events happen that might cause its visibility to have changed...  only to find out that a `View`'s visibility can only be changed by calling `setVisibility()` and not by overriding `getVisibility()`.  See Romain Guy's answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6796299/view-getvisibility-isshown-return-incorrect-visibility).

Is there is a particular method that gets called as part of the normal `View` lifecycle/rendering process that would be ideal to override, in which I would call `setVisibilty()`?  Since I already call `invalidate()`, overriding it to call `setVisibility()` works.  But is that the ideal place for it?  It seems like setting a `View`'s attributes in `invalidate()` would go against best practices.

**Clarification:**  Andr has pointed out that there are many things that might cause the custom `View`'s visibility to change and those scenarios are very specific the custom view's usage.  That's very true.  But this question isn't about how to *trigger* the appearance to refresh - `invalidate()` seems to be the standard way of telling Android that a View's appearance has changed, is it not?  Instead, this is a best practices question about *where* to call `setVisibility()` once the custom `View` has been invalidated.  I wouldn't want to made changes in the wrong part of the process, like in `onMeasure()` for example.  If anyone has links, I would love to see a diagram of Android's UI rendering process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such a general method, simply because no method of `View` may cover all possible situations in which its visibility should be recomputed (just think about asynchronous events changing your visibility, e.g. change in the state of a network operation; or even a simple timer going off).

You, as the developer, know what are the cases in which visibility should be invalidated and you should modify the visibility accordingly exactly at that points. Of course it would be possible to always set the visibility before every layout and drawing, but:

- I suspect it would not cover all cases.
- It would probably be weird to understand after a month or two.
- It's an overkill - it's a mobile device you're dealing with and you should keep its limitations in mind and aim for efficiency.

Having said that, I really don't see the point of calling `invalidate()` after setting the visibility - it's done automatically by the platform. I would suggest simply:

```
private void invalidateVisibility() {
    // calculate visibility
    setVisibility(calculation_outcome);
    //invalidate();
}
```

and change calls to `invalidate()` to `invalidateVisibility()`. If you really need to call `invalidate()` for some reason - just uncomment the call. This will probably be the most efficient solution.

**Edit:**

The point of my answer was to suggest something as general as your described logic seemed to be (at least for me) at the time of writing. I assumed you have some crucial processing going on in the `invalidate()` method and so, you need to call it. However, your question bugged me for a while and after reading it 4 or 5 times, I think I finally realized what exactly are you asking! :)

If I understand you correctly, you're *already* calling `invalidate()` every time the visibility of the `View` may have changed. *Because of that*, for the sake of simplicity, you want to incorporate modification of the view visibility into the invalidation process.

If that's the case then you're right - doing that as a first thing in `invalidate()` is perfectly OK. That's why I put the calls exactly in that order in `invalidateVisibility()`:

- When a `View` is becoming visible its parent gets notified about the need to repaint and calling `invalidate()` afterwards should simply "group with the previous one" (this is because all pending paint operations are handled in one batch).
- When a `View` has turned invisible it automatically signals itself for invalidation. Another call to `invalidate()` will simply be a no-op.

Then there's intuition - this:

```
button.setVisible(false/true);
button.invalidate();
```

doesn't seem to be suspicious code. And effectively that's what your `invalidate()` will turn into. However, verify that the computation of visibility is a quick operation because `invalidate()` may be called by the Android platform *many* times per second. This is mostly the case when the UI is animated - e.g. updating bounds of a view during a pinch gesture.

Hope that helps in any way :)

Comment: I'm not calling invalidate() after setVisibility(). I'm invalidating and want to set visibility in one of the View's standard callbacks. I'm just looking for the ideal one.  As for the suggestion, invalidateVisibility() seems to be reinventing the wheel for no reason. Wouldn't relying on invalidate() and tying into the standard process be much better? And requiring API clients to call such a specific one-off method suggests that they have enough insight into the view's display logic to know that their actions have affected the View's visibility specifically. Kind of defeats the purpose.

Comment: Thanks for your update.  Sorry if my question maybe wasn't clear initially.  I think your last comment about `invalidate()` getting called repeatedly was kind of to my point.  In API's like Android, it's sometimes hard to tell where the ideal place is to "tie into" the existing process.  Some methods may not get called in all of the circumstances you expect, and others may get called far too frequently.  So thanks for your response.