# Button wont turn visible when clicking

Tags: android, xml, visibility

I have a button i would like to make visible and invisible on every click of an image view.
I have tried setting Invisible/Visible but it won't work.

**this is my code:**

```
public class FullScreenImageAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    Button btnClose;
    private Activity _activity;
    private ArrayList<String> _imagePaths;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    // constructor
    public FullScreenImageAdapter(Activity activity,
                                  ArrayList<String> imagePaths) {
        this._activity = activity;
        this._imagePaths = imagePaths;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return this._imagePaths.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == ((RelativeLayout) object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        TouchImageView imgDisplay;

        inflater = (LayoutInflater) _activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View viewLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_fullscreen_image, container,
                false);
        hideBar();
        imgDisplay = (TouchImageView) viewLayout.findViewById(R.id.imgDisplay);
        btnClose = (Button) viewLayout.findViewById(R.id.btnClose);
        Picasso.with(_activity)
                .load(_imagePaths.get(position))
                .placeholder(R.drawable.loader)
                .fit()
                .centerCrop().into(imgDisplay);

        // close button click event
        btnClose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                _activity.finish();
            }
        });

        imgDisplay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                hideBar();
                hideButton();
            }
        });

        ((ViewPager) container).addView(viewLayout);

        return viewLayout;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        ((ViewPager) container).removeView((RelativeLayout) object);
    }

    public void hideBar() {
        View decorView = _activity.getWindow().getDecorView();
        int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
    }

    public void hideButton() {
        if (btnClose.isShown()){
            btnClose.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }else{
            btnClose.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
    }
```

**this is my xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<com.example.shaka.we.ImageHelper.helper.TouchImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgDisplay"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnClose"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:background="@drawable/redx"
    android:paddingBottom="2dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="2dp"
    android:visibility="invisible"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

can someone help me?

Comment: what part of the code is responsible for making it visible?

Comment: have you tried putting logs in or breakpoints to see if you're getting to the block of code you're expecting?

Comment: you can check this question for help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6796299/view-getvisibility-isshown-return-incorrect-visibility

Comment: i checked it. it won't work for me. i'll keep looking. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check whether a view is visible by using `view.getVisibility()` or `view.isShow()`. But remember that:  `isShow() returns the visibility of this view and all of its ancestors. True if this view and all of its ancestors are visible`, and `getVisibility() returns the visibility status for this view, which are VISIBLE, INVISIBLE, GONE. True if this view is visible`. In your case, the button has a parent that is always visible, so the `btnClose.isShown` is true, so you are always executing the `btnClose.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);` when you click the imageview.

Comment: I tried it, it now shows the correct state of the button but it won't hide it.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void hideButton() {
    if (btnClose.isShown()){
        btnClose.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }else{
        btnClose.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

calling `isShown` is not a good way of checking if a view is displayed or visible. Check for its actual visibility like below

```
public void hideButton() {
    if (btnClose.getVisibility() != View.VISIBLE){
        btnClose.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }else{
        btnClose.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
}
```

Comment: what is it doing instead?

Comment: I added this code: 'public void hideButton() {
        if (btnClose.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){
            Toast.makeText(_activity, "Turn invisible", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            btnClose.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }else{
            btnClose.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Toast.makeText(_activity, "Turn Visible", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }' it always shows Turn Invisible but wont set the visibilty off

Comment: what is special about this class TouchImageView

Comment: it's just a simple adapter